Add shipping address to user on registration
I am working on a craftcms + commerce project and I need to add a shipping address to new user during its registration process. The idea is to have a shipping address added to any newly registered user (no billing address needed).
Is it possible to add shipping address fields in the same registration process or do i need to create 2 step form or something?

I have not yet had to do this in Craft 5, but the following is how I did it in Craft 4 - it required some custom module code to hook into the EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT event which triggers when a User is registered. You might also be able to use EVENT_AFTER_ASSIGN_USER_TO_DEFAULT_GROUP instead.

use Craft;
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\services\Elements;
use craft\events\ElementEvent;
use craft\elements\Address;

...

// --------------------------------------------
// SAVE ADDRESS AFTER REGISTRATION
// --------------------------------------------

Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent $e) {
        // bail out on console requests
        if (Craft::$app->request->isConsoleRequest) { return; }

        // Bail out on CP requests
        if (Craft::$app->request->isCpRequest) { return; }

        // bail out if it's not a user element being saved, just to triple check ourselves
        if (!$e->element instanceof \craft\elements\User) { return; }

        // else continue...
        $add1 = Craft::$app->request->getBodyParam('address');

        $userId = $e->element->id;
        $address = new Address();

        $address->ownerId = $userId;
        $address->title = 'Address';
        $address->fullName = '';
        $address->addressLine1 = $add1['addressLine1'];
        $address->addressLine2 = $add1['addressLine2'];
        $address->locality = $add1['locality'];
        $address->postalCode = $add1['postalCode'];
        $address->countryCode = 'GB';
        $address->administrativeArea = $add1['administrativeArea'];

        // Save the address
        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($address);
    }
);

The registration form is as normal, with {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }} and then you can name the address inputs however you like e.g. name="address[addressLine1]" and then wire them up in the function above. This code actually originally came from a Craft 3 site where it was even more difficult if I recall (as Addresses were part of Commerce but not really part of core Craft), so it's possible there might even be a more native way now - I just went for the simplest possible upgrade route from 3 to 4. Hopefully it can at least help you get it working in 5.
